# Не удается загрузить сайт через selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

При попытке открыть сайт через selenium chromeDriver ничего не происходит, просто долгое время идет загрузка. Если открываю сайт в ручную через браузер, то ошибка "Не удается получить доступ к сайту", либо загружается частично. Используемый код:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.common.exceptions import *

 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\Administrator\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
 driver.get("https://www.myscore.ru/")
```

Раньше сайт открывался без проблем. Другие сайты открываются нормально. Версии драйвера и браузера совместимы. Кто знает в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Самому интересно стало что за проблема такая, скопировал код, запустил - всё работает)

Comment: Сайт может заблокировать мой ip?

Comment: Вполне, попробуйте использовать прокси

Comment: Как это можно сделать, не подскажите?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11450158/how-do-i-set-proxy-for-chrome-in-python-webdriver

Comment: Ищите бесплатные прокси сервера, и попробуйте на нескольких, ибо они часто не рабочие бывают

Comment: Спасибо буду пробовать. Изначально перестал заходить через selenium, но в ручную через хром на сайт заходил. Теперь и в ручную не могу зайти на сайт. Попробовал и на своём пк и на выделенной сервере, везде теперь не заходит..

Comment: А в ручную если на сайт заходите, то тоже все без проблем открывается?

Comment: Да, всё работает

Comment: Можно ещё посмотреть через Fiddler, что сайт отдаёт